# Should I comment out the code for what I am not testing when loading the test firmware for Ramps 1.4?

Tags: ramps-1.4, firmware

> You may want to use [this code](http://reprap.org/wiki/File:RAMPSTestCode.pde) to test all the electronics before
>   installing any of the suggested firmwares.

I'm planning on:

1. Flashing the [test firmware](http://reprap.org/wiki/File:RAMPSTestCode.pde) onto the Arduino Mega 2560, then unplugging it from the USB.
2. Connecting RAMPS 1.4
3. Connecting all 3 jumpers under the X-Axis (leaving the other jumpers disconnected).
4. Connecting a stepper driver to the X-Axis on the board.
5. Turning the trimpot down all the way, and then back up 1/4th of the way.
6. Plugging in 1 NEMA 17 motor to the X-Axis.
7. Connecting 5A DC input into RAMPS 1.4 (not plugged in).
8. Finally plugging it in and seeing if the motor moves for 5 seconds.

Now my question is, if I'm going to do this to test out a single NEMA 17 motor, do I need to comment out the rest of the test code before loading the firmware?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to comment anything out. It will work just fine without any modification, even if you're just testing a single motor. That said, I don't see the value of this "test firmware" over just installing Marlin.

Comment: Somebody must see the value in it, since they wrote it, but maybe it's no longer valuable, but it was at the time.